# I want to fill the checkbox on page load if the value is true in the object and when the checkbox is clicked

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js, checkbox, element-plus

On loading the page, I load all the notifications that are array of objects. Each object has an isRead value that is a boolean.
I want the checkbox in the table to be filled with a check mark if the value isRead = true for a certain object, and if not, to leave the checkbox empty. And when the checkbox is clicked to add/remove its value in the object.
If it's not a problem, I'd like you to write me the code because I'm new to vue and Typescript

```
`This is component : `

const notificationStore  = useNotificationStore() 
let allNotifications = ref<NotificationData[]>([])
let isNotificationRead = ref<boolean>(false)

const isDeleteDialogOpen = ref(false)
const isEditDialogOpen = ref(false)


async function getAllNotifications() {
  try {
    let response = await notificationStore.getNotifications();
    allNotifications.value = response.data.data;
    console.log(allNotifications.value)
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  allNotifications.value.forEach((el) => {
        if(el.isRead == true){
          let isNotificationRead = true
        }
        else {
          let isNotificationRead = false
        }
    });
}

getAllNotifications()

</script>

<template>
  <Section>
<template #title>
  Notifications
</template>

<template #body>
    <el-table :data="allNotifications" style="width: 100%">
        <el-table-column label="Updated At">
            <template #default="prop">
                <el-row>
                    <span style="margin-left: 10px">{{ prop.row.updatedAt }}</span>
                  </el-row>
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column label="Message">
            <template #default="prop">
                <el-row>
                    <span style="margin-left: 10px">{{ prop.row.message }}</span>
                </el-row>
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column align="right">
            <template #default="prop">
                <el-checkbox v-model="prop.isNotificationRead"  label="Read" size="small" />
                  <el-icon >
                    <Delete @click="isDeleteDialogOpen = true" />
                  </el-icon>
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
</template>
  </Section>

  <el-dialog
    v-model="isDeleteDialogOpen"
    title="Are You Sure You Want to Remove This Notification?"
    align-center
    :show-close="false"
  ><template #header="{ close, titleId, titleClass }">
        <h3 >Are You Sure You Want to Remove this Notification?</h3>
    </template>
    <span>This will remove </span>
    <span class="point-out-text">{{}}</span>
    <span> from use. This will delete all the items it contains. Are you sure you want to remove it?</span>
    <template #footer>
      <span>
        <el-row justify="end">
          <el-button type="danger" @click="">
            Yes, remove it
          </el-button>
          <el-button @click="isDeleteDialogOpen = false">
            Cancel
          </el-button>
        </el-row>
      </span>
    </template>
  </el-dialog>

  <el-dialog
    v-model="isEditDialogOpen"
    show-close
  >
  <template #header>
  <DialogHeading>
      <template #title>Edit Notification</template>
      <template #subtitle>Edit the existing Notification. Change notification description...</template>
    </DialogHeading>
  </template>
  <template #footer>
      <span>
        <el-row justify="end">
          <el-button type="primary" @click="">
            Save
          </el-button>
          <el-button @click="isEditDialogOpen = false">
            Cancel
          </el-button>
        </el-row>
      </span>
    </template>
  </el-dialog>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
`
this is form of data : `data": [
        {
            "id": "6f81bfca-94a5-4cc9-93c0-48fa7d10c866",
            "userId": "8565fe35-e2e8-4d98-8c21-b06688501a63",
            "message": "Category Design you have experience in has been removed.",
            "isRead": true,
            "createdAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:48.305202",
            "updatedAt": "2023-01-24T12:25:18.412720",
            "deletedAt": null
        },
        {
            "id": "20d22d45-553f-4926-a6df-9014a277cd80",
            "userId": "8565fe35-e2e8-4d98-8c21-b06688501a63",
            "message": "Category Backend you have experience in has been removed.",
            "isRead": false,
            "createdAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:16.969621",
            "updatedAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:16.969621",
            "deletedAt": null
        },
        {
            "id": "2cca79e5-1b68-4aad-b8fc-4581e758347d",
            "userId": "8565fe35-e2e8-4d98-8c21-b06688501a63",
            "message": "Category Frontend you have experience in has been removed.",
            "isRead": false,
            "createdAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:11.622430",
            "updatedAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:11.622430",
            "deletedAt": null
        }
    ]`
`
```

I'm waiting for a good person to help me because I've tried really everything and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: you can directly pass `isRead` in v-model instead of creating a new variable. `<el-checkbox v-model="prop.row.isRead"  label="Read" size="small" />`

Comment: Rohìt Jíndal God bless you Sir <3

Comment: I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by passing the prop `isRead` into the `v-model` instead of creating a separate variable which is not associated with the objects separately and as `v-model` work as a two way data binding it will update the `isRead` property value automatically.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      tableData: [
        {
          "id": "6f81bfca-94a5-4cc9-93c0-48fa7d10c866",
          "userId": "8565fe35-e2e8-4d98-8c21-b06688501a63",
          "message": "Category Design you have experience in has been removed.",
          "isRead": true,
          "createdAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:48.305202",
          "updatedAt": "2023-01-24T12:25:18.412720",
          "deletedAt": null
        },
        {
          "id": "20d22d45-553f-4926-a6df-9014a277cd80",
          "userId": "8565fe35-e2e8-4d98-8c21-b06688501a63",
          "message": "Category Backend you have experience in has been removed.",
          "isRead": false,
          "createdAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:16.969621",
          "updatedAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:16.969621",
          "deletedAt": null
        },
        {
          "id": "2cca79e5-1b68-4aad-b8fc-4581e758347d",
          "userId": "8565fe35-e2e8-4d98-8c21-b06688501a63",
          "message": "Category Frontend you have experience in has been removed.",
          "isRead": false,
          "createdAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:11.622430",
          "updatedAt": "2023-01-23T09:19:11.622430",
          "deletedAt": null
        }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateCheckBox(rowId) {
        this.tableData.forEach(row => {
          if (row.id === rowId) {
            console.log(row.isRead)
          }
        })
    }
  }
}
var app = Vue.extend(Main)
new app().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.2/lib/index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.2/lib/theme-chalk/index.css"/>

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <el-table :data="tableData" ref="table" border style="width: 500px">
      <el-table-column label="Updated At">
            <template #default="prop">
                <el-row>
                    <span style="margin-left: 10px">{{ prop.row.updatedAt }}</span>
                  </el-row>
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column label="Message">
            <template #default="prop">
                <el-row>
                    <span style="margin-left: 10px">{{ prop.row.message }}</span>
                </el-row>
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
        <el-table-column align="right">
            <template #default="prop">
                <el-checkbox v-model="prop.row.isRead"  label="Read" size="small" @change="updateCheckBox(prop.row.id)"/>
            </template>
        </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: yes thank you very much i just gave v-model="prop.row.isRead" and it works for me.
Now I need the second part to save that value on the change so that the changed object is pushed back to the database

Comment: @Trpimir As i said it will automatically update the object `isRead` value. You have to just pass whole data object on save.

Comment: it underlines in red rowId and is saying : Parameter 'rowId' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Comment: @Trpimir As you are using typescript, You can just assign a type to this parameter `updateCheckBox(rowId: string)`. This will resolve this warning.